# Mapping over Prismic Slice Data in Gatsby App

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, prismic.io

I have a "Single Type" Page in Prismic with some normal content fields like `uid` or `headline`. It also has slice content with non-repeatable fields.

This is what my query looks like:

```
export const homeQuery = graphql`
  query Home {
    prismicHome {
      data {
        page_title {
          text
        }
        introline {
          text
        }
        hero_headline {
          text
        }
        body {
          ... on PrismicHomeBodyProjects {
            __typename
            primary {
              client_name {
                text
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

And in my page I am returning it like this:

```
const IndexPage = ({ data: { prismicHome } }) => {

  return(
    <LayoutHome>
      <Hero
        introline={prismicHome.data.introline.text}
        headline={prismicHome.data.hero_headline.text}
      />
    </LayoutHome>
  )
}
```

But what I can't find out is how to map over my slice fields (i.e. `client_name`) without using the ApolloClient the are using in their docs?

My first naive attempt failed and returns a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`:

```
const projects = homeQuery.prismicHome.data.body.primary.map(({ client_name }) =>
  <div>
    <h2>{client_name}</h2>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: What do you get if you conosle log `prismicHome ` in your page component?

Comment: Hey ksav! Sorry for the slow response, could figure it out as I misunderstood how those arrays are nested. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ChristophBerger can you expand on your findings? I'm dealing with the same, I'm guessing you found something wrong with your path into the slice but I can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @master sure, I misunderstood how to map over data from slices, after mapping over the data you should use a switch statement to check for the various slices:

```
class ComponentName extends Component {

render() {
  const slices = this.props.data.QUERYNAME.body.map(slice => {
    switch (slice.slice_type) {
      case "slice_name":
        return (
          <Component
     prop={slice.primary.FIELDNAME.TYPE}
          />
        )
      default:
        return null // or whatever you want to return in case it breaks
    }
  })
}

return (
 {slices}
)

}
```

Comment: @master, sry totally broke the code preview, will add it as another comment below, please feel free to reach out again if it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//First add 'slice_type' to your slice query
...

... on PrismicHomeBodyProjects {
        slice_type
        __typename
        primary {
          client_name {
            text
          }
        }
      }
 ...


// Sort and display the different slice options

const PostSlices = ({ slices }) => {

  return slices.map((slice, index) => {

    const res = (() => {

      switch (slice.slice_type) {

        case "projects":
          return (
            <div className="slice" key={index}>
              {slice content...}
            </div>
          )
        default:
          return
      }
    })()

    return res
  })
}

  // Define the Post content returned from Prismic
  export default (props) => {

  const doc = props.data.prismicHome.edges.slice(0, 1).pop();
  const slices = doc.node.data.body;

  return (
    <div>
      <PostSlices slices={slices} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hey, figured it out a while ago and while answering @master s question above I saw your comment. Thank for that anyway.

Quick question though, why are you recommending switching to the other plugin?

Comment: it has full support for Prismic Previews. It fetches data using Prismic's beta GraphQL API. It also provides an easy-to-configure interface for page generation.

Comment: [Update] I do not recommend the gatsby-source-prismic-graphl plugin anymore since it's not getting regular maintenance. So i'd say, stick with gatsby-source-prismic Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To provide an answer to @master s comment, I am putting my code bits here:

```
class ComponentName extends Component {

render() {
  const slices = this.props.data.QUERYNAME.body.map(slice => {
    switch (slice.slice_type) {
      case "slice_name":
        return (
          <Component
        prop={slice.primary.FIELDNAME.TYPE}
          />
        )
      default:
        return null // or whatever you want to return in case it breaks
    }
  })
}

return (
 {slices}
)

}
```